# Call Result of one Class and use it in other Class

Tags: c#, class, function, call

It might be easy but im stuck!

i do have a class that Create one Command for me like:

As you can see this Encode will Return me bCommand!

Now im having a Button Function that i should call this bCommand and Assign it as a Value like:

So i got the Error that Bcommand Does not Exist in Current Context
I'm looking for any advice how i can Solve the Problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the results of the `Encode` method to a variable.

```
private void btnModel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    byte[] bCommand = Encode("C11", "");
    WriteData(bCommand);  // bCommand will now exist in this context
}
```

Comment: Can i ask something?                    You see in my Encode Function im having this :    Array.Copy(bCmd, 0, bCommand, 5, bCmd.Length); how i can reverse the result! im using reverse function but its not work

Comment: @Artinos You want to reverse the entire result of `Encode`. I would say something like `var bCommand = Encode("C11", "").Reverse().ToArray();` or if you want the result to be reversed before it is returned you could use `return bCommand.Reverse().ToArray();` in the `Encode` method.

Comment: Well my bad because i just did and my mistake was i do reverse after assign it to bCommand which is not going to work but now its fine

Comment: @Artinos I'm glad you got it figured out.